# Q Promises - Create a dynamic promise chain then trigger it

Tags: promise, q

I am wondering if there's a way to create a promise chain that I can build based on a series of `if` statements and somehow trigger it at the end. For example:

```
// Get response from some call
callback = (response) {
    var chain = Q(response.userData)

    if (!response.connected) {
        chain = chain.then(connectUser)
    }

    if (!response.exists) {
        chain = chain.then(addUser)
    }

    // etc...

    // Finally somehow trigger the chain
    chain.trigger().then(successCallback, failCallback)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise represents an operation that has already started. You can't `trigger()` a promise chain, since the promise chain is already running.

While you can get around this by creating a deferred and then queuing around it and eventually resolving it later - this is not optimal. If you drop the `.trigger` from the last line though, I suspect your task will work as expected - the only difference is that it will queue the operations and start them rather than wait:

```
var q = Q();
if(false){
    q = q.then(function(el){ return Q.delay(1000,"Hello");
} else {
    q = q.then(function(el){ return Q.delay(1000,"Hi");
}
q.then(function(res){
      console.log(res); // logs "Hi"
});
```

The key points here are:

- A promise represents an already started operation.
- You can append `.then` handlers to a promise even after it resolved and it will still execute predictably.

Good luck, and happy coding

Comment: Yea I had tried that, I found it was another bug in my code that prevented it from working. Fixed that and it was all green :)

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin says ...

... but you might also like to consider something slightly different. Try turning the code inside-out; build the then chain unconditionally and perform the tests inside the `.then()` callbacks.

```
function foo(response) {
    return = Q().then(function() {
        return (response.connected) ? null : connectUser(response.userData);
    }).then(function() {
        return (response.exists) ? null : addUser(response.userData);//assuming addUser() accepts response.userData
    });
}
```

*I think you will get away with returning nulls - if `null` doesn't work, then try `Q()` (in two places).*

If my assumption about what is passed to `addUser()` is correct, then you don't need to worry about passing data down the chain - `response` remains available in the closure formed by the outer function. If this assumption is incorrect, then no worries - simply arrange for `connectUser` to return whatever is necessary and pick it up in the second `.then`.

I would regard this approach to be more elegant than conditional chain building, even though it is less efficient. That said, you are unlikely ever to notice the difference.